# XSL: Remove parent and add namespace prefix

Tags: xml, xslt

I have problem to remove xml parent element and then add namespace to other elements.

Can someone help ?

I have this XML

```
<DOutput>
    <xxxOut>
        <ES>
            <Error a="1" b="10" c="900" d="blabla"/>
        </ES>
    </xxxOut>
</DOutput>
```

I need to get this..

```
        <cc:xxxOut>
            <cc:ES>
                <cc:Error a="1" b="10" c="900" d="blabla"/>
            </cc:ES>
        </cc:xxxOut>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:cc="http://example.com/cc"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="cc:{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DOutput">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working well.